# CentOS 6 Apache Virtual Host Config Help for Development Server

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, virtualhost, lamp

I have setup a LAMP server with CentOS. It will be used as a development server within our domain. It is our first Linux server and would like to actually put one into production in the future.

The DNS Domain Name for this server is webserv8.DOMAIN.com and has an internal IP assigned to it 10.64.3.55

I can get the first (http://webserv8.DOMAIN.com) host to host to work, but I cannot get the second virtual host (http://TESTSITE.webserv8.DOMAIN.com) to work.

**Here is what I have in my vhost.conf file.**

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerAdmin joe.****@DOMAIN.com
 ServerName webserv8.DOMAIN.com
 DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
 ErrorLog /var/www/error/error.log
 CustomLog /var/www/error/access.log combined
</Virtualhost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerAdmin joe.****@DOMAIN.com
 ServerName TESTSITE.webserv8.DOMAIN.com
 DocumentRoot /srv/www/TESTSITE/public_html/ 
</Virtualhost>
```

Thank you for your help!
Joe

Comment: What error are you seeing? Does public_html have any content?

Comment: I'd install webmin and use that to configure the new vhost, you can then look in the httpd config file to see what it wrote for you. You'll have to give more information about what happens than expect us to guess - it could be filesystem, permissions, dns, etc

Answer (score 0):

Have you created the DNS entry for TESTSITE.webserv8.DOMAIN.com ?
Can you ping it?

Does /srv/www/TESTSITE/public_html/ exist?

Have you reloaded restarted apache?

I would also go and make everything lowercase.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an actual answer...